# How can I pack_row into compact table?

Tags: r, kableextra

I wanted to pack rows only for the "so3" categories while excluding the other activities in output table. The issue I'm facing is that the pack_rows function appears to include all the activities, not just the "so3" categories though so3 analysis table doesn't include all activities. Really appreciate if you could fix it. Thanks in advance!

[image: so3_analysis_table]
[image: output table]

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

so3_analysis <- fsc %>%
  filter(!is.na(so3_category)) %>%
  group_by(activity_red, so3_category) %>%
  summarise(beneficiaries = sum(new_beneficiaries), .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(activity_red) %>%
  mutate(`%_of_ben` = round(beneficiaries / sum(beneficiaries) * 100, digits = 2)) %>%
  rename(so3_sub_category = so3_category, agriculture_activity = activity_red)   

kable(so3_analysis, caption = "Breakdown of agriculture activities by sub-category", 
      format.args = list(big.mark = ",")) %>%
  pack_rows(index = table(so3_analysis$agriculture_activity)) %>%
  kable_classic_2("striped")
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible question: include the output of `dput(fsc)` .  A helpful link for asking questions: [MRE].